# Rails - Using ajax to upload images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've been trying to upload an image using ajax, but maybe I'm doing it wrong

```
<%= simple_form_for @note, remote: true do |f|%>
  <%= f.text_area :content%>
  <%= f.file_field :picture %>
  <%= f.submit "save"%>
<%end%>
```

but every time I hit save... it is not doing the upload, it goes to the show action instead of displaying the alerts that I have in the file create.js.erb (it does have the multipart parameter in the form label.
Is it possible to upload an image using this way? or should I check the jquery-file-upload library?

Thanks in advance

Javier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not use Ajax for a file upload. But you can use e.g. the fileupload plugin for jQuery http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

I had the same problem --> [form_tag with remote: true does not make an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374897/form-tag-with-remote-true-does-not-make-an-ajax-request)

Comment: well that makes sense :), I've seen that plugin. What should I search in google in order to understand why it is not possible?

Comment: this helped too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595049/why-cant-i-upload-files-asynchronously

Comment: in my projects with a file upload, I use the jQuery file upload. As soon as a file is selected, it is uploaded to my server and a response is send to the user. If the file passes the tests, it is a html including a hidden id. If the file fails, I send an error message to the user.

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery.form plugin for file upload through ajax. Here is a link for that.

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/