# Rails 4, submitting a form by ajax and uploading an image by paperclip gives error: InvalidAuthenticityToken

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, paperclip, csrf

Using rails 4, I am submitting a form by ajax using remote: true in for_for tag.
I have a field to upload image in the form, for image upload paperclip is used.

If I submit the form without uploading image everything works fine.
But If I upload a image and then submit the same form I get following error:

```
ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken(ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)
```

I tried using, "authenticity_token: true" as follows:

```
<%= form_for @user, :remote => true, authenticity_token: true, :html=>{:class=>"form_validation ", :multipart=>true }  do |f| %>
```

This above piece of code does not give me InvalidAuthenticityToken error but the form is submitted by html and not js(ajax).
I want to submit form by ajax.

Is this a CSRF issue or any other issue related to paperclip?
Can anyone help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly upload files by ajax, you need to use [jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) or [jQuery-File-Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/) plugins to make it possible. You need to go through their documentation. Take a look at this question

[form_tag with remote: true does not make an ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374897/form-tag-with-remote-true-does-not-make-an-ajax-request)

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, but i already have gem 'remotipart' in my gem file. The link which you provided above has the solution to user remotipart gem, I am exactly using same way. Now the error is not coming but for is getting submitted by HTML ( Processing by UsersController#create as HTML ) and not JS (ajax)

Answer (score -1):

Please read links below and I am sure you will find something useful:

[rails 4 authenticity token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258911/rails-4-authenticity-token)

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb?source=cc